# Connecting to a mongoDB with a TCP prefix on a NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, tcp, mongoose

I created a NodeJS app that connects with a MongoDB and it seems to work locally.

Now, after hosting the NodeJS application on a remote machine, I am trying to connect to a mongoDB that was already created on that machine.  When I print out some of the environment variables, the only one I see of relevance seems to be :

`MONGODB_PORT: 'tcp://172.30.204.90:27017',`

I tried connecting like I usually do with
 `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/metadata/')`
and replacing it with `mongoose.connect('tcp://172.30.204.90:27017/metadata')` but I get an error that says my URI needs to start with 'mongodb'.

So I tried replacing it with `mongoose.connect('mongodb://172.30.204.90:27017/metadata')` and it no longer throws any error.  But on the MongoDB side I don't see any new connections happening and my app does not start up on the machine.  What should I be putting in the URI?

Answer (score 0):

Your URI should indeed start with mongodb:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?options...');
```

See this page for more information: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Did you try to connect to the database from cli? Or Telnet to see that connection isn't blocked.

Comment: it was not blocked, but there was no acceptance either, nothing seems to connect